# Iferror/Vlookup using variables

Tags: excel, vba

I have recorded an Excel function (Iferror/Vlookup) which I need to modify to inpput variables to make it more dynamic (Allow for columns moving).  Below is a brief outline of what I want to do.  The First section is the recorded Function and the variables I want to add.  The second section is my proposed solution.  My problem is I need to drop the function into excel and copy it down over 50,000 rows.  So my error handling solution won't work here.  Is it possilbe to make the original recorded function dynamic using iferror/Vlookup.  Any help appreciated.

```
Dim Lookup1         As Long
Dim LookupOffset    As Long
Dim LRange          As Range


Lookup1 = -99
LookupOffset = 28

Set LRange = Column("CU:CV")

With Worksheets("consolidated")

        .Cells(2, 99).FormulaR1C1 = _
             "=RC[-71]-IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-12],C[-2]:C[-1],2,FALSE),0)"
        .Cells(2, 99).Copy Range(.Cells(2, 99), .Cells(glLastRow, 99))
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        .Calculate

 End With

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Proposed Solution
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim Res As Variant
On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear
Res = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Lookup1 - LookupOffset, LRange, 2, False)
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Value found by VLookup. Continue normal execution.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Else
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Value NOT found by VLookup. Error handling code here.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
End If
```

Comment: Two things: What is the 'normal' formula equivalent of your `VLOOKUP` (I can figure it out from the above, but I want to be sure), and, should it really be `VLOOKUP`? A simple offset using VBA will be relatively quicker to set-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub LookUpMod()

    Dim wSht As Worksheet: Set wSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidated")

    With wSht
        On Error Resume Next
        .Cells(2, 99).Formula = "=XCV34-IFERROR(VLOOKUP(XFC34,$I:$J,2,FALSE),0)"
        .Range(Cells(2, 99), Cells(glLastRow, 99)).FillDown
        .Calculate
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

End Sub
```

Just noticed, though, that you don't have `glLastRow` instantiated properly. Let us know if this helps.

**EDIT:**

As per chat with OP:

```
Function LookUpMod(Str As Variant, Rng As Range, OffsetToRight As Long)
    Application.Volatile
    LookUpMod = Rng.Cells.Find(What:=Str).Offset(0, OffsetToRight).Value
End Function
```

A simple flexible lookup is what is needed.

Comment: @user1624926: Thanks for accepting. Just to let you know: error handling in `VBA` is handled by that line up there (`On Error...`). One can use it to skip errors altogether (not entirely safe, but quick and painless) or do specific things per error type. :)

Comment: @user1624926: Why did you retract the accept? Is it not what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the answer - However using "XCV34-IFERROR(VLOOKUP(XFC34,$I:$J,2,FALSE),0)" I can't use variables.  E.G XFC34 (lookup) I need it to be a Dim's Long variable that I can set outside the formula.  Any ideas?

Comment: @user1624926: Fair enough. So basically, you want `XFC34` to be a flexible cell? How about `XCV34`? Should it be the on the same row as `XFC34`?

Comment: I'm trying to have everything flexible within the Vlookup.  The iferror is making it difficult.  The solution I posted works but I can't wrap it in a "Iferror".  I can't use an error handler as I need to drop the function into Excel - I don't know how to get around it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43404/discussion-between-bk201-and-user1624926)